# Read a raw as html format

Tags: r, rvest

In this format:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1,2), text = c("<h1> Title </h1> keep me here <h1>not </h1> or <h2> else</h2>","also not here <h1> but</h1> here also")
```

How is it possible to read the first line of the df1 text column as html in order to receive the inner text of h1 tag.

Here what I tried:

```
library(rvest)
rawHTML <- paste(df1$text[1], collapse="\n")
rawHTML %>%
     html_node("h1") %>%
     html_text() %>%
     as.numeric()
```

The error:

```
Error in UseMethod("xml_find_first") : 
  no applicable method for 'xml_find_first' applied to an object of class "character"
```

Expected output using the full dataframe

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2), title = c("keep me here", 0))
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @DarrenTsai I added a line with the expected output. Thank you. I would like to receive whatever text exist after the h1 tag with inner text Title and create a new column where 0 exist when in the corresponding row there is no h1 tag with Title inside

Comment: Would `read_html()` do the job? `rawHTML %>% read_html() %>% html_node("h1") %>% html_text()`

Comment: @user12728748 how about to check only h1 which have as inner text the Title word?

Comment: @user12728748 thank you I would like to receive the text after this. Any idea for this please?

Comment: In your example, the only words in h1 tags are " Title " and " not ". You can get both with `rawHTML %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes("h1") %>% html_text()`. Not sure where the numeric 0 should come from?

Comment: @user12728748 I would like to receive the text after it